# How to change the system alert like privacy button colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

can i modify the button colours of system generated alerts like photos, location privacy etc in my iOS app

Comment: No. We cannot change it. Other thing is AlertView are not meant to be subclassed.

Comment: But in new ios alertViews are deprecated by UIalertControllers and all. Still we can not change them ?

Comment: Same applies to UIAlertController taken from apple documentation `The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No. We cannot change it**, Inside our application we can change, by default message provided by apple we can not handle it.

from the [UIAlertView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html):

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.